# C: Convert from decimal to hexadecimal using bitwise operations

Tags: c

I have to convert a decimal number to octal and hexadecimal using bitwise operations. I know how to convert it to binary:

```
char * decToBin(int n)
{
    unsigned int mask=128;
    char *converted;
    converted=(char *) malloc((log((double) mask)/log((double) 2))*sizeof(char)+2);
    strcpy(converted,"");

    while(mask > 0)
    {
        if(mask & n)
            strcat(converted,"1");
        else
            strcat(converted,"0");

        mask >>= 1;

    }

    return converted;
}
```

May you help me convert from decimal to hexadecimal? What should the basic idea be? Is it possible to use a mask for that? Thank you.

Comment: Just to be precise, you are not converting from decimal here.

Comment: How many bits does an octal digit take? A hexadecimal digit?

Comment: @DanielFischer octal: 4? hexadecimal: 5?

Comment: Close, but not quite.  And if this is homework, please tag it as such.

Comment: With binary done, you simply need to know that there are 3 bits per octal digit, 4 bits per hexadecimal digit, and your conditional in the loop for the binary will not extend well to either octal or hex.  Also, it is conventional to place the LSB (least significant bit) of the result at the right-hand end of the string; your binary code places it at the left-hand end.  You simply need to reverse the generated string.

Comment: the example is only converting 8 bits, and not an entire `int`, is that all that is needed?  It always generates 8 characters, and doesn't trim leading zeros, is that the required behaviour?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could "cheat" and use `sprintf`:

```
char *conv = calloc(1, sizeof(unsigned) * 2 + 3); // each byte is 2 characters in hex, and 2 characters for the 0x and 1 character for the trailing NUL
sprintf(conv, "0x%X", (unsigned) input);
return conv;
```

Or, to elaborate on @user1113426's answer:

```
char *decToHex(unsigned input)
{
    char *output = malloc(sizeof(unsigned) * 2 + 3);
    strcpy(output, "0x00000000");

    static char HEX[] = "0123456789ABCDEF";

    // represents the end of the string.
    int index = 9;

    while (input > 0 ) {
        output[index--] = HEX[(input & 0xF)];
        input >>= 4;            
    }

    return output;
}
```

Comment: @OliCharlesworth shh, don't tell anyone :)

Answer (score 1):

I am not fluent in C, but you can use this pseudo code:

```
char * decToHex(int n){
     char *CHARS = "0123456789ABCDEF";
     //Initialization of 'converted' object
     while(n > 0)
     {      
        //Prepend (CHARS[n & 0xF]) char to converted;
        n >>= 4;
     }
     //return 'converted' object
}
```